# Как соединить две функции Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть две функции Javascript

Первая-обновляет страницу в заданный интервал:

```
timeout = prompt("Set timeout [s]");
current = location.href;

if (timeout > 0) 
    setTimeout('reload()', 1000 * timeout);
else 
    location.replace(current);

function reload() {
    setTimeout('reload()', 1000 * timeout);
    fr4me = '<frameset cols=\'*\'>\n<frame src=\'' + current + '\'/>';
    fr4me += '</frameset>';

    with(document) {
        write(fr4me);
        void(close())
    };
}
```

Вторая-нажимает кнопку на сайте:

```
javascript:document.querySelectorAll('div.icon-play-button')[2].click();
```

Как бы  не пробовал, у меня не получается настроить нажатие кнопки каждый раз после обновления страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вызывать метод после того, как страница полностью загрузится. В этом поможет слушатель у документа и его метод `DOMContentLoaded`

```
function ready() {
    document.querySelectorAll('div.icon-play-button')[2].click();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Comment: не помогло. Не нажимает на кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

Скрипты, вызванные или запланированные на странице до выполнения, не будут исполняться после обновления. Всё необходимое должно быть сделано уже после.

Можно сохранить перед обновлением в `sessionStorage` какой-нибудь флаг, указывающий, что кнопку надо нажать, а потом проверить наличие флага и нажать кнопку. При этом надо не забыть удалить флаг.

Ну и если ты хочешь запустить видео, то используй `autoplay`. Но если оно не `muted`, то оба способа всё равно скорее всего не заработают.